# Where is the C# export steema TeeChart modal dialog window for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, teechart

I've trying to locate the available tchart export dialog window API in C# for WPF.  I've tried accessing Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Editors but the only class available is AboutBox.  Can someone provide details on where I can gain access to this predefined window if there is one?  In C and Forms, to bring up the export dialog window is as follows:

```
#include <Teexport.hpp>

TTeeExportForm *tmp=new TTeeExportForm(this);
try
{
    tmp->ExportPanel=Chart1;
    tmp->ShowModal();
}
__finally
{
    delete tmp;
}
```

Hence I'm trying to find the C# equivalent if it exists.

Robert

Comment: In WinForm you need to add a ChartEditor and call editorChart.ShowModal();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't exist. TeeChart editors are not supported in TeeChart.WPF.dll. You should export  charts at run-time as explained in tutorial 12. Tutorials can be found at TeeChart's program group.

Comment: Can you link to the tutorials that you are referring to, or include the main parts of it here?

Comment: @Default the tutorials are included with the fully functional evaluation version available at http://www.steema.com/download/net. Also, you'll find several examples at the Steema Support forums, for example: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14245&p=62702&#p62698